# In Python, how do I inspect and then re-raise an exception while maintaining the original call stack?

Tags: python, exception, callstack

I've got a situation where I'm catching a specific exception type, inspecting the exception's message to check if it's actually an exception I want to catch, and then re-raising the exception if not:

```
try:
    # do something exception-prone
except FooException as e:
    if e.message == 'Something I want to handle':
        # handle the exception
    else:
        raise e
```

This works fine, with one problem. In the case I re-raise the exception, that exception now occurs at the line I re-raised it (i.e. at `raise e`), rather than at the location the exception originally occurred. This isn't ideal for debugging, where you want to know where the original exception happened.

Thus my question: is there any way to re-raise or otherwise "pass on" an exception after catching it while maintaining the original exception location?

NOTE: In case you are wondering what the actual situation is: I'm dynamically importing some modules using `__import__`. I'm catching `ImportError` to gracefully deal with the case that any of these modules do not exist. However, in the case that any of these modules themselves contain an import statement that raises `ImportError`, I want those "real" (from the point of view of my application) exceptions to be raised -- and at the original location as far as debugging tools are concerned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just do:

```
raise
```

instead of `raise e`. See the tutorial section on [raising exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions), and also the [language reference on `raise` statements](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise):

> If no expressions are present, raise re-raises the last exception that was active in the current scope. If no exception is active in the current scope, a TypeError exception is raised indicating that this is an error (if running under IDLE, a Queue.Empty exception is raised instead).

Comment: Duh! Easy. I was looking at the reference for try/except and forgot to look at raise. Thanks.