# Catch , Process and Re-Raise Exception of any type with same type

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, try-catch

I'm doing some DB updates during my python application so I need to catch all exceptions (i.e. `except` without type or with general `Exception` type) to rollback DB
But I also need to re-raise the exception for parent functions in the call stack so they can do their clean up too.

I can re-raise the exception by wrapping them in `Exception` class but i need to preserve their type

How can I re-raise catched exception of any type preserving their type and data in python?

Comment: You can simply do `except ExceptionType as e: #do stuff` and then `raise e`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to re-raise an exception in nested try/except blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188563/how-to-re-raise-an-exception-in-nested-try-except-blocks), [In Python, how do I inspect and then re-raise an exception while maintaining the original call stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209450/in-python-how-do-i-inspect-and-then-re-raise-an-exception-while-maintaining-the)